# How do I call $form_state->getValue() to get as value in an array?

Tags: 8, forms

I created a form for a block plugin. I'm attempting to save the values to the form after submitting. However, I'm having trouble saving the values that are in an array.

```php
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['plugins_string_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => $this->t('Block contents'),
    '#format' => 'full_html',
    '#description' => $this->t('This text will appear in the block.'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['plugins_string_text-submit'],
  );

  $form['header']['margin-top'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Margin Top (pixels)'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['header']['margin-top-submit'],
  );

  $form['header']['margin-bottom'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Margin Bottom (pixels)'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['header']['margin-bottom-submit'],
  );

  $form['header']['margin-left'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Margin Left (pixels)'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['header']['margin-left-submit'],
  );

  $form['header']['margin-right'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Margin Right (pixels)'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['header']['margin-right-submit'],
  );
}

public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->configuration['plugins_string_text-submit']  = $form_state->getValue('plugins_string_text');
  $this->configuration['header']['margin-top-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-top');
  $this->configuration['header']['margin-bottom-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-bottom');
  $this->configuration['header']['margin-right-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-right');
  $this->configuration['header']['margin-left-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-left');
}
```

This is properly saved.

```php
$this->configuration['plugins_string_text-submit']  = $form_state->getValue('plugins_string_text');
```

However, each of the following lines displays the entirety of the 'header' array instead of the individual values.

```php
$this->configuration['header']['margin-top-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-top');
$this->configuration['header']['margin-bottom-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-bottom');
$this->configuration['header']['margin-right-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-right');
$this->configuration['header']['margin-left-submit'] = $form_state->getValue('header','margin-left');
```

How do I call `$form_state->getValue()` to get the value of an element in an array?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Put the keys in an array, for example:

```
$this->configuration['header']['margin-top-submit'] = $form_state->getValue(['header','margin-top']);
```

Comment: I finally got this to work, but only after adding ...
'#tree' => TRUE
... to a parent element (fieldset in my case, but a fieldgroup will work and maybe others).

Comment: @DelfordChaffin Did you use the '#tree' => TRUE at a container or a fieldset ??

Comment: Thanks  @DelfordChaffin. '#tree' => TRUE in my fieldset  was the secret sauce to getting the array.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in drupal 8 after many hours of testing. I hope it helps.

```
public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $is_live = $form_state->getValue('settings')['is_live '];
}
```

Comment: After "many hours of testing", I finally got this to work after adding `$form['account']['#tree'] = TRUE;`